# PHP count null or 'new' elements within array

Tags: php

My array is below.  What I am trying to do is count the number of nodes in the array have null or 'new' for read_status.

Is there something more sufficient than looping through the array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 428
            [read_status] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 427
            [read_status] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 441
            [read_status] => new
        )  
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 341
            [read_status] => read
        )  
)
```

So the count should be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with looping in the array to do this, it might actually be faster than using a generic method to do it for you. It's simply this :

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($arrays as $entry)
{
    if (!$entry['read_status'] || $entry['read_status'] === "new")
    {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count;
```

Comment: Minor improvement: use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: My personal pet peeve of PHP devs is: they're always asking "how do I do X to an array, without looping".

Comment: I changed it to ===, might as well.

Comment: @TravisO should I not be concerned about looping?  I was taught looping was not most efficient.  Was I taught wrong?  Can you explain why it's your pet peeve?

Comment: @Mike looping is only slow if you are doing something complex or slow within the loop (ex: never do a SQL call inside a loop).  If you just write an empty loop and have it run like  a million times, it won't take up any noticeable time.

Comment: Mike, also note that if you use a generic function to do it, it will need to loop anyway. You can't escape loops for your current problem.

Comment: @DanyCaissy got you.  so one way or another, this puppy is looping.

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
$count = count(array_filter($myArray, function($item){
    return $item['read_status'] != 'new';
}));

echo $count;
```

but I think its more efficient to just loop through it like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($myArray as $item){
    if($item['read_status'] != 'new')$count++;
}

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually improved my SQL by removing the null completely -- so now read_status is either read or new.

```
IF(feed_read.read_status IS NULL,'new','read') AS read_status
```

From there, I was able to utilize another SO question in order to count the 'new' elements.

```
$counted = array_count_values(array_map(function($value){return $value['read_status'];}, $result));
echo $counted['new'];
```